# Styled components vs props.children

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have been working with react using css modules till now. I wanted to switch to styled components and there is one thing that confuses me. When working with css modules i have been creating many UI components as wrappers, passing props.children in between and then styling the wrapper in specific ".module.css" file. Now when i saw how styled components work, its like creating a component and styling that one element or even styling nested jsx tags. So styled components have wrapper behaviour. Does it kinda replace usage of props.children?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, `Styled Components` do not force you not to use `props.children`.
You can use a *Styled Component* as a wrapper and style children inside of it as you would do with a Component styled with a css.module:

I guess you are composing your React components like this:

```js
// css.module
// styles.module.css

.container {
background-color: red;
}

.container > h2 {
color: green;
}

// Your React Component Wrapper:

const Wrapper = ({children}) => <div className={styles.container}>{children}</div>


// And you use it like this:

<Wrapper><h2>This text is green on a red background</h2></Wrapper>
```

You can do the same thing with Styled Components:

```js
const Wrapper = ({ children }) => <StyledWrapper>{children}</StyledWrapper>;

const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
background-color: red;
& > h2 {
color: green;
}
`;

// And you use it like this:

<Wrapper><h2>This text is green on a red background</h2></Wrapper>
```

The result is the same and even the usage is the same, `styled-components` do not force you to use a certain React Composition Pattern, it's up to you whether to style container and then select children inside of it, or if to individually style all the children.

They just give you some *super-powers*, for example you can target a *Styled Component Child* inside a *Styled Component Parent*, by simply calling the Component name, or you have the chance to use JS variables more easily into your css code, since all props passed to a Styled Component can be retrieved by the css.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vj5nv8?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Ye, but what is the point then if u can just replace the "Wrapper2" tag to "StyledWrapper" and it will be working the same?

Comment: That depends on how you handle the Wrapper. If your Wrapper is a dumb Component with no logic, yeah, you can simply use the Styled Component as a wrapper, since it automatically renders its children. You did provide no code or additional info on your question, so my answer  targets a generic approach where you might have a `Wrapper` having also some logic, and possibly passing props to the Styled Component.

Comment: Anyway, you cleared my mind about this, thanks.